# How to acquire a remote host fingerprint that is not in known_hosts?

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-access

`ssh-keygen -l -F host` will print out the key of a remote host, but only if the host exists in `known_hosts`.Is it possible to request a fingerprint from a host that isn't in the known_hosts file? (without manual intervention such as connecting through ssh)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `ssh-keyscan`, e.g.:

```
$ ssh-keyscan 192.168.25.16
# 192.168.25.16 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze3
192.168.25.16 ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz[...]ThruGvpQ==
```

Optionally pass the `-H` option to get hashed names as you're seeing in a `known_hosts` file.

See also [U&L: How to get the public key from sshd server without touching the known_hosts file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38053/23363)